# MobileVLCKit player shows black screen on iOS 11

Tags: ios, mobile, vlc, ios11, xcode9

In my project using **MobileVLCKit 3.0.0** for playing media.

All types of videos successfully playing on iOS9&10 but on **iOS 11 video audio able to listen but the picture doesn't display and shows the black screen**.

Gives below logs:

```
2017-09-18 18:26:17.640065+0800 DemoPlayer[39923:369260] creating player instance using shared library
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 39923, TID: 369593, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   DemoPlayer                          0x0000000108349895 Open + 405
2017-09-18 18:26:23.490963+0800 DemoPlayer[39923:369593] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 39923, TID: 369593, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   DemoPlayer                          0x0000000108349895 Open + 405
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView initWithFrame:]
PID: 39923, TID: 369593, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   DemoPlayer                          0x0000000108349f3b -[VLCOpenGLES2VideoView initWithFrame:zeroCopy:voutDisplay:] + 91
2017-09-18 18:26:23.875359+0800 DemoPlayer[39923:369593] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView initWithFrame:]
PID: 39923, TID: 369593, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   DemoPlayer                          0x0000000108349f3b -[VLCOpenGLES2VideoView initWithFrame:zeroCopy:voutDisplay:] + 91
2017-09-18 18:26:23.959355+0800 DemoPlayer[39923:369593] CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush].
shader program 1: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord1' not read by fragment shader
WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord2' not read by fragment shader
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, got the solution...

Now 'MobileVLCKit-Unstable' version updated into master on Sep 20 with UIKit from a background thread(iOS 11 Video play) issue.

Solution1:

Add `pod 'MobileVLCKit-unstable', '3.0.0a38'` to podfile and run `pod install`

Solution 2:

1. Cloned the repo from the following URL: http://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit.git
2. Open terminal, navigate to root directory and execute `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -f` (Note: It may take 1-2 hours to complete)
3. On successful completion, the `MobileVLCKit.framework` will be generated in VLCKit/build/ folder location.
4. Simply drag it to your project.

Comment: I tried the above method, after executing the above script i couldnot see the VLCKit/build/ folder

Answer (score 1):

You need to update MobileVLCKit to the pod 'MobileVLCKit-unstable' in version '3.0.0a38' or later. This problem was resolved. There is no way to make older releases of the library work in any way as it calls to UIKit from a background thread.

Comment: Hi Feepk, I'm trying to install mentioned pod but does not able to install. tried with pod ‘MobileVLCKit-unstable’ '3.0.0a38',  pod try MobileVLCKit-unstable. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: Also created new project and just tried with these commands a) pod try 'MobileVLCKit-unstable' '3.0.0a38' b) pod try 'MobileVLCKit-unstable'
OUTPUT:
Updating spec repositories
.
.
Trying MobileVLCKit-unstable
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /private/var/folders/p3/jzgk4rcj1s15r_w9d2j9cqn40000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/MobileVLCKit-unstable/file.zip https://download.videolan.org/pub/cocoapods/unstable/MobileVLCKit-unstable-3.0.0a38-4d3db120.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional